# Panning point cloud model in CloudCompare

Tags: cloudcompare

Im running [CloudCompare](http://www.danielgm.net/cc/) on my Mac via the OSX build.

Is there a pan tool in CloudCompare so that i can pan model as opposed to just being able to just rotate it ?

Answer (score 2):

Hold right click to pan the pointcloud, or the equivalent of right click on your system.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac use (control)drag to pan.